# Weird Zoom Behavior Using TouchImageView with Specific Phone

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-pageradapter, touchimageview, android-pagetransformer

Not sure what is going on here but I have implemented the Zoom features on an image-gallery in a ViewPager, ImagePagerAdapter using TouchImageView.  On all my other phones and tablets the code works perfect, for zooming and page flipping.  On 3 of our Motorola Razrs the Zooming acts funny on the first image.  By funny I mean that when you try and zoom nothing happens on picture #1.  But if you pan to the next image the zooming from image 1 has affect image 2.  If you flip back to image 1 it still doesn't zoom.  If you pan to image #3 then back to #1 the first image will zoom just fine.  Not sure how to tackle this issue or even debug it.  I have added custom animation, DepthPageTransformer, from the examples in API.  This is the culprit, but not sure what in the code is causing this behavior.

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.PageTransformer;
import android.view.View;

public class DepthPageTransformer implements PageTransformer {
    private static final float MIN_SCALE = 0.55f;

    // suppress compiler warning...lower Api use standard slide in but 
    // APIs higher than 10 will use the transform page function
    @SuppressLint("NewApi") 
    public void transformPage(View view, float position) {
        int pageWidth = view.getWidth();

        if (position < -1) { // [-Infinity,-1)
            // This page is way off-screen to the left.
            view.setAlpha(0);

        } else if (position <= 0) { // [-1,0]
            // Use the default slide transition when moving to the left page
            view.setAlpha(1);
            view.setTranslationX(0);
            view.setScaleX(1);
            view.setScaleY(1);

        } else if (position <= 1) { // (0,1]
            // Fade the page out.
            view.setAlpha(1 - position);

            // Counteract the default slide transition
            view.setTranslationX(pageWidth * -position);

            // Scale the page down (between MIN_SCALE and 1)
            float scaleFactor = MIN_SCALE + (1 - MIN_SCALE) * (1 - Math.abs(position));
            view.setScaleX(scaleFactor);
            view.setScaleY(scaleFactor);

        } else { // (1,+Infinity]
            // This page is way off-screen to the right.
            view.setAlpha(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the animation was causing this weird behavior.  Not sure why but until I figure it out I had to remove the setting of this animation.

```
galleryViewPager.setClickable(true);
//galleryViewPager.setAnimation(new DepthPageTransformer());
galleryViewPager.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {...
```

Now the fling animation is using the standard.  Must be the way the Motorola Razr implements the adapter fling animation that messes up the listener order.